# Simplify REST put/post calls

Tags: rest, express, post, put

Using express.Router() with Postgres backend, when writing put/post it can be quite laborious to enter each db field separately.  For example:

router.route('/bears/:bear_id')
    .get(function(req, res) {
        ...
    })

```
.put(function(req, res) {
    Bear.findById(req.params.bear_id, function(err, bear) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        bear.name = req.body.name;
        bear.field1 = req.body.field1;
        bear.field2 = req.body.field2;
        bear.field3 = req.body.field3;
        bear.field4 = req.body.field4;
        bear.moreFields = req.body.moreFields;
        etc.

        bear.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            res.json({ message: 'Bear updated!' });
        });
    });
});
```

So - - is there a pattern or a JS tool that can automatically spread all the object names to the proper req.body name assuming that the JSON key values and the db field name are the same?

I don't want to use an ORM.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For *POST* verb just add body to create method:

```
  Bear.create(req.body).then(function() {
      //...
  });
```

For *PUT* verb, you have to find the document in database as usual and then update it in loop

```
Bear.findById(req.params.bear_id, function(err, bear) {
    for (let elem in req.body) {
        bear[elem] = req.body[elem];
    }

    bear.save((err, bear)=> {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        } else {
            res.json({ message: 'Bear updated!' });
        }
    });
});
```

Package body-parser has to be installed.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't mention that I'm not using Mongo as my back end.  Using Postgres.  UPDATED my question.